# vtkCubeAxesActor SetUserTransform() having no influence

Tags: c++, vtk

I try to set a transformation on an vtkCubeAxesActor. This is the code where i setup the actor and set the transform

```
// define axis actor
vtkNew<vtkCubeAxesActor> axesActor;
axesActor->SetBounds(bounds);
axesActor->SetCamera(renderer->GetActiveCamera());    
axesActor->DrawXGridlinesOn();
axesActor->DrawYGridlinesOn();
axesActor->DrawZGridlinesOn();
axesActor->SetGridLineLocation(axesActor->VTK_GRID_LINES_FURTHEST);
axesActor->XAxisMinorTickVisibilityOff();
axesActor->YAxisMinorTickVisibilityOff();
axesActor->ZAxisMinorTickVisibilityOff();

// transform to nice scale for plotting
vtkNew<vtkTransform> transform;
transform->Scale(1.0, 2.0 , 3.0);
axesActor->SetUserTransform(transform);
```

However when i do this the vtkCubeAxesActor still looks the same as before (not scaled) with my other actors the scaling works without any problem.

Any ideas where the problem is, or how else i could solve the scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO goaran :).

Have a look at [vtkCubeAxesActor.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/0ce0d74e67927fd964a27c045d68e2f32b5f65f7/Rendering/Annotation/vtkCubeAxesActor.cxx) source and header [vtkCubeAxesActor.h](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/7df7c32cb938d1d379e3c0843a26faf07a695672/Rendering/Annotation/vtkCubeAxesActor.h) and you imediatelly see the answer. 
Here is a summary what I found so far:

1. `UserTransform` is not present at all in the source code i.e. not
   used
2. `vtkAxisActors` are created by `vtkCubeAxesActor`

   `this->XAxes[i] = vtkAxisActor::New();`

   `this->YAxes[i] = vtkAxisActor::New();`

   `this->ZAxes[i] = vtkAxisActor::New();`
3. Properties mentioned above are not exposed in any way e.g. by `vtkCubeAxesActor->GetActors2D(collection);` or `vtkCubeAxesActor->GetActors(collection);`

This means by default you aren't able to transform `vtkCubeAxesActor` as other `vtkActor`.
What you can do is to change the header of `vtkCubeAxesActor.h` to expose the actors, put them into a container, iterate through it and call transform.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPropCollection> collection = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPropCollection>::New();
cubeAxesActor->GetActors2D(collection);
collection->InitTraversal();
cubeAxesActor->GetXAxesGridlinesProperty()-
for(int i = 0; i < collection->GetNumberOfItems(); i++)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkActor::SafeDownCast(collection->GetNextProp());
    actor->SetUserMatrix(transform->GetMatrix());
}
```